# Removing Parent if child doesn't contain comment using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using  Jquery or Javascript,

I want to remove the div (.item) if there is no comment

The div structure :

```js
$('.item').css("display", "none");
$(function() {
  $('.two').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 8) {
      this.parent('.item').css("display", "inline-block");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <a class="link">
    <div></div>
    <div class="two">
      <img>
      <!-- <div class="hidden-div"></div> -->
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I made this Jquery code but there is a problem with it

```
$('.item').css("display", "none");
  $(function () {
    $('.two').contents().each(function () {
      if (this.nodeType == 8) { 
        this.parent('.item').css("display", "inline-block");
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: hi, what is exactly your problem ? The code snippets are not running (jquery missing)

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this:

```
$('.item').contents().filter(function(){
  return this.nodeType == 8;
}) // returns contents with comment
.end() // back to .item
.css('display','none'); // set display to .item
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , buy the code doesn't working well
first it remove all div class item + i want to only remove which doesn't contain comment

i think the only way is to tell JS that if the next node after <img> isn't comment then hide the parent

Answer (score 0):

i did it using this code

```js
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.two');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 var currentElement = elements[i];
 if (currentElement.childNodes.length < 7) {
  currentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
 }
}
```